# React require("history").createBrowserHistory` instead of `require("history/createBrowserHistory")

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, history.js

So basically i am having a problem in using the history library in react.

Is it because of the latest version should i try to downgrade the history version but as the error states that `Support for the latter will be removed in the next major release.` so how should i change and where should i change it?

it says:

```
Warning: Please use `require("history").createBrowserHistory` instead of `require("history/createBrowserHistory")`. Support for the latter will be removed in the next major release.
```

AND

```
Warning: Please use `require("history").createHashHistory` instead of `require("history/createHashHistory")`. Support for the latter will be removed in the next major release.
```

I am not quite sure how to fix it.

```
import createHistory from './history'

import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux'
import { routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/es/storage'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import createRootReducer from './reducers'

export const history = createHistory();

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage
};

const reducers = persistReducer( persistConfig, createRootReducer(history));
const exampleMiddleware =  store => next => action => {
  // if (action.type === 'message'){
  //   do something
  // } else {
  //   next(action);
  // }
}

export default () => {
  const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(routerMiddleware(history), thunk, exampleMiddleware))
  );
  let persistor = persistStore(store)

  return  { store, persistor }
}
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider, ReactReduxContext } from 'react-redux';
// import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'

import configureStore, { history } from './configureStore'
import Routers from './Routers';

const { persistor, store } = configureStore();

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <Provider store={store} context={ReactReduxContext}>
        <div> SYNTIFY </div>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>

          <ConnectedRouter history={history} context={ReactReduxContext}>
            <Routers />
          </ConnectedRouter>

        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

history.js

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
export default createHistory;
```

As it showing error nothing gets rendered.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Import `creatBrowserHistory` with curly brackets. It's exported as a [named export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).

```
// history.js

import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

Then import and use it in index.

```
// index.js
import history from "./history";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store/store";

const AppContainer = () => (
    <Router history={history}>
        <Provider store={store}>
             <Route path="/" component={App} />
        </Provider>
    </Router>
);
```

Comment: Just a note, mostly it is the issue as mentioned by @Giwan but rarely as it happened in my case, I had passed the component incorrectly in the <Route component={<div>hi</div>} /> (imported from react-router-dom). Removal of that resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Why did you define `Router` before the redux store `Provider`?

Comment: @vsync no particular reason. I don't believe the order matters in this case.

Answer (score 17):

I've changed this 
`import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'`

to this
`import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'`

Answer (score 3):

In my code, this error occurs when running a unit test. An enzyme or jest is possible by interpreting the ES6 code differently. Make in the package history export default.

My import code now

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
```

Here is the full `history.js` code

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

Answer (score 2):

Having the solution approved above wasn't enough for me:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

I solved this issue updating `react-router` and `react-router-dom` to:

```
"react-router": "^5.3.3",
"react-router-dom": "^5.3.3"
```

Comment: Mine was the same, the above fix alone wasn't enough. Mine (for node 16) required:

    "react-router": "4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",

Answer (score 1):

goto node_modules > dva > lib > index.js 
[image]

index.js
[image]

source from: https://www.cnblogs.com/fairylee/p/11198868.html

Answer (score 1):

Using the suggestion I was able to get rid of the error in the console on render.

```
// NO IMPORT ABOVE  (just set the import directly to a variable)
    const history = require("history").createBrowserHistory()


// then you can 
if( *some-requirement*){
history.push("/desiredRoute")
}. 
// right from your App.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Install this version of `react-router-dom@5.2.0`. If there is an error, install `webpack@3.1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

just create new file for history and add

```
    import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
    export default createHistory();
```

import history from 'the file path created for history it will work'

Comment: Can i just directly import it and use it? updted my answer above pls look

Comment: yes you can direclty import it in App component and attach it to ConnectedRouter

Comment: @kishanJiswal Can you see the code above? i updated my configStore.js and it still shows the same error

Comment: i will suggest to keep separate file for history and import and use

Comment: @kishanJiswal look at the edit code above. is that what you meant?
It didnt work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191060/discussion-between-nick-bb-and-kishan-jaiswal).

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am facing .a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

This import worked for me `var createHistory = require('history').createBrowserHistory;`
instead of this import `import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';`
The history file is given below:

```
var createHistory = require('history').createBrowserHistory;
export default createHistory();
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the **React-Router-Dom** library

If you're using **yarn**

write => `yarn add React-Router-Dom`

it will automatically update to the current version of Router library

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFjaz.png)

Answer (score 0):

try this

- go to `node_modules/history/createBrowserHistory` and do as the warning says
- delete this ('createBrowserHistory') replace it with this in new line: `require("history").createBrowserHistory`

then

- go to `node_modules/history/createHashHistory`
- delete ('createHashHistory') replace it with this in new line: `require("history").createHashHistory`

Answer (score 0):

you need an API migration,

```
// createBrowserHistory  was createHistory in createBrowserHistory
import { createBrowserHistory as history} from 'history'

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store/store";

const AppContainer = () => (
    <Router history={history}>
        <Provider store={store}>
             <Route path="/" component={App} />
        </Provider>
    </Router>
);
```

Thx to @CrsCaballero's